# How to disable the magnifying window function while holding on the text?

Tags: system, android-11, accessibility, text-editor, nokia

Recently, I changed my phone to Nokia 6.2 with Android 11 system and I find a new feature that is really user-unfriendly to me. In my old phones when I press and hold on the text in an address bar(or any place where a long line of text is displayed in a single row), I can slide the line of text to find the exact part that I want to edit, but this doesn't work in my new phone, for when I hold on the text now, a magnifying window will appear (as showed in the screenshot below) instead, and I cannot make the texts that's not fit into the screen appear.

This is really annoying. Is there any way to disable this useless magnifying function?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This works on my phone running 11, so my guess is that the Accessibilty option is enabled.

Check

1. Settings
2. Accesibility Options
3. Disable magnification / Zoom options

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this doesn't work for me. The Magnification option in Accessibility is already disabled…